# iOS UISearchBar always translucent

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

I have `UISearchBar` and I have set the `Translucent` property to `false` both in the Xcode editor and in code.

However the `UISearchBar` always remains translucent and it looks terrible next to my navigation bar, which I have also set the `Translucent` to `false`.

How can I set the `UiSearchBar` bar tint color without it being translucent?

**Rant**:
Why on earth would iOS not let you set the color of a component exactly as you want it? To sneakily alter the color in the background is unbelievable!

**Edit**

**Code to set the translucent to false.**

```
historySearchBar.Translucent = false;
```

**Designer set translucent off.**

[image: Designer translucent off]

**Result is still a translucent UISearchBar.**

[image]

Comment: can you provide your code?Or some screenshot?

Comment: @LucasZ I have added code and a screen shot.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LucasZ I want the navigation bar and the search bar to be exactly the same color.

Comment: Have you set the  BarTintColor  of the NavationBar?

Comment: I did the same as you .But the color are same.

Comment: To fix the issue for now, I have set the global bar tint color for the search bar in the `AppDelegate` `FinishedLaunching`: `UISearchBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Bluel;`